# apply a function using strsplit in big matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix of dimension 8Million rows x 109 columns. A subset of this matrix looks like this:

```
df <- matrix(c("0.221,0.767,0.011" ,"0.97,0.03,0",       "0.967,0.033,0",
               "0.922,0.077,0.001", "0.664,0.329,0.007", "0.953,0.047,0", 
               "0.993,0.007,0",     "0.994,0.006,0",     "0.992,0.008,0",
               "0.477,0.52,0.002",  "0.953,0.047,0",     "0.993,0.007,0", 
               "0.994,0.006,0",     "0.992,0.008,0",     "0.476,0.521,0.003",
               "0.952,0.048,0" ,    "0.993,0.007,0",     "0.994,0.006,0",
               "0.992,0.008,0", "0.485,0.512,0.003"), ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
```

I need to make a series of calculations in this matrix. For example, if `x <- df[1,1]`, then I would need to do multiply twice the first element `0.221` and sum to the result to the second element `0.767`.

The result would look like this:

```
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
  [1,] 1.209 1.970 1.967 1.921 1.657
  [2,] 1.953 1.993 1.994 1.992 1.474
  [3,] 1.953 1.993 1.994 1.992 1.473
  [4,] 1.952 1.993 1.994 1.992 1.482
```

I using this solution provided by @erocoar, that works nicely for a small dataset:

```
out <- lapply(strsplit(df, ","), function(x) {
x <- as.numeric(x)
return((2 * x[1]) + x[2])
})
out <- do.call(rbind, out)
dim(out) <- dim(df)
```

However this solution requires a lot of memory and takes a lot of time in my real dataset. I also have tried this:

```
y = function(x) {a <- strsplit(x, ",")
    z <- as.numeric(a)
    return((2 * z[1]) + z[2])
    }
 m <- matrix(-9, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = ncol(df))
 m[] <- vapply(df, y, numeric(1))
```

But this gives me an error about format.

**UPDATE**

the original file comes from a vcf file (genetic variant file) where genetic info is stored,

First I have read the file with `read.vcfR`, here is the code:

```
library(vcfR)
vcf <- read.vcfR("/mnt/lustre/scratch/home/proximal.vcf.gz")
df <- vcf@gt
df <- dosages[, -1]
df <- gsub(".+:.+:(.*)", "\\1", dosages, perl = TRUE)
```

And then I would like to make the calculations in the first part of the post

Comment: Have you tried writing the result of each loop to a file? If you're worried about RAM memory, this should take care of that issue. As far as taking time, the `do.call(rbind, ...)` is likely slowing you way down. Writing and reading from files will likely speed things up naturally.

Comment: No, I didn't could you provide me with an example @CPak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any loops, Just read the data again. This time the `sep` character being defined twice. For the paste `sep=\n` and for the `read.table` `sep=\n`.

First make your matrix as a `dataframe`. Paste the columns together rowwise, then read it back in again.

```
 dd=do.call(paste,c(data.frame(df),sep="\n"))
 m=read.table(text=dd,sep=",")
 matrix(2*m[,1]+m[,2],4,byrow=T)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] 1.209 1.970 1.967 1.921 1.657
[2,] 1.953 1.993 1.994 1.992 1.474
[3,] 1.953 1.993 1.994 1.992 1.473
[4,] 1.952 1.993 1.994 1.992 1.482
```

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu, but reading the `dd` takes a lot of time, any way to speed the process, my dataframe has 8 million rows and 110 columns

Comment: How did you read it in in the first place? That might give us a solution.

Comment: I have updated the question so you can see the first steps

Comment: But that does not answer the question I asked. How you read the matrix.

Comment: I read the original file with `read.vcfR` and it gives me the matrix, after removing some info with `gsub`

Comment: try:`A=tapply(scan(text=df,sep=","),rep(1:prod(dim(df)),each=3),function(x)2*x[1]+x[2]);matrix(A,nrow(df))`

Comment: you can also use the `gsubfn` package  `b=gsubfn::strapply(df,"(\\d+[.]\\d+),(\\d+[.]\\d+)",function(x,y)2*as.numeric(x)+as.numeric(y),simplify = c); matrix(b,dim(df))`